# rtl8822be wifi not working ubuntu 18.04 (bluetooth works)

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking

I recently bought an ASUS vivobook s15.  It comes with a rtl8822be wifi/bluetooth NIC.  I dual boot windows 10 and ubuntu 18.04.  I have no problem with the wifi / bluetooth in windows10.  In linux, bluetooth works but wifi does not.  I can see the interface using 'ip link list' but it is in 'DORMANT' mode.  The driver and the interface are showing up, but something is broken within the driver (or the kernel).  I saw on other forums (listed below) that rtl8822be is supported in 18.04, so this is very strange...

I have tried:

- setting aspm=0
- blacklisting the bluetooth modules
- building driver from source from lwfinger's github page
- fresh installs
- manually controlling interface
- setting powersave=2 (off) in network manager config file
- more...

Here are some command outputs:

```
mobile3@mobile3-VivoBook:~$ lsmod | grep 8822
r8822be               688128  0
mac80211              815104  4 ath9k_htc,rtwpci,rtw88,r8822be
cfg80211              675840  6 ath9k_htc,ath9k_common,ath,mac80211,rtw88,r8822be

mobile3@mobile3-VivoBook:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 8822
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter [10ec:b822]
Kernel modules: rtwpci, r8822be

mobile3@mobile3-VivoBook:/opt$ uname -r
5.0.0-27-generic

mobile3@mobile3-VivoBook:/opt$ sudo ip link list
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: wlp1s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
link/ether dc:f5:05:c7:fd:8d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

It seems that the driver is working but for some reason the wifi portion of the NIC cannot be fired up.  Some similar threads are:
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=266219
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067286/still-no-wifi-adapter-for-realtek-rtl8822be-found-in-18-04
https://askubuntu.com/questions/926364/how-to-make-my-pci-wifi-card-rtl8822-working-on-ubuntu

EDIT1: I have confirmed that on the 19.04 LiveUSB I have wifi and the RTL8822BE chip works, but when I do an install the wifi does not work!

**EDIT2:**  I have posted an answer below.  Basically I rolled back the kernel to 5.0.0.13.  For someone experiencing a similar issue, I noticed that NetworkManager is struggling to set the interface UP and ends up disconnecting it:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/tmp/kern$ journalctl | grep wlp1s0
Sep 09 23:27:13 ubuntu kernel: rtw_pci 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: renamed from wlan0
Sep 09 23:27:13 ubuntu NetworkManager[1308]: <info>  [1568071633.5581] devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.4/0000:01:00.0/net/wlp1s0, iface: wlp1s0)
Sep 09 23:27:13 ubuntu NetworkManager[1308]: <info>  [1568071633.5581] device added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.4/0000:01:00.0/net/wlp1s0, iface: wlp1s0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Sep 09 23:27:13 ubuntu NetworkManager[1308]: <info>  [1568071633.5582] device (wlp1s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Sep 09 23:27:14 ubuntu NetworkManager[1308]: <info>  [1568071634.1258] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
Sep 09 23:27:14 ubuntu NetworkManager[1308]: <info>  [1568071634.1258] device (wlp1s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 09 23:27:25 ubuntu NetworkManager[1308]: <info>  [1568071645.9281] device changed (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.4/0000:01:00.0/net/wlp1s0, iface: wlp1s0)
Sep 09 23:28:50 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[1310]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=DRIVER type=CUSTOM_WORLD
Sep 09 23:28:50 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[1310]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=DRIVER type=INTERSECTION
```

Comment: I'm not a Linux expert but I think you can try `ifup wlp1s0` (run as root)

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 thanks for the response, but unfortunately I have tried setting the interface up manually via several methods (ifconfig, ip, ifup, network-manager, etc.).  I have some more information and I will update my post.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the latest linux kernel 5.0.0.27 is the source of the problem.  When I boot using an older kernel, 5.0.0.13, the RTL8822be chipset works fine for wifi and Bluetooth.  My Disco (19.04) LiveUSB uses 5.0.0.13.  I then did an install of Ubuntu 19.04 with the 5.0.0.13 kernel, and it worked.

For other users experiencing a similar issue: you may want to try rolling back the kernel or switching to 19.04.  After a fresh install of 19.04 I booted on kernel 5.0.0.13, then ran apt-get update and apt-get upgrade, and everything worked after a reboot (again to 5.0.0.13).  There must be some kind of bug in the kernel, but I'm a nuclear scientist not a kernel engineer and as such I leave that battle to the experts...

EDIT / UPDATE 20191110
FYI to anyone else experiencing this issue, the latest version of ubuntu18 seems to work.  You may have to get the latest linux kernel and recompile drivers, but I am running ubuntu 18 LTS with this r8822be driver and it works after rebuilding kernel drivers.

Comment: That's weird. Consider [filing a report](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) on this.

Answer (score 1):

A guy called mid-kid has a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/mid-kid/r8822be) with the RTL8822BE driver that works flawlessly in Ubuntu 20.04 for me.

Here's how to setup the driver:

```sh
sudo apt install build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/mid-kid/r8822be.git
cd r8822be
./make

# Remove the misbehaving rtw88 module
sudo rmmod rtwpci rtw88

# Install the r8822be module
sudo ./make install
sudo modprobe r8822be
```

The WiFi card should be active now.

Answer (score 0):

run the command 
echo "options r8822be aspm=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/r8822be.conf

run the command 
sudo rmmod r8822be

run the command 
sudo modprobe r8822be

Comment: Why would these command help?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I already tried switching the antenna and removing / replacing the kernel module.  As it turns out, the latest kernel version on ubuntu18 seems to work.  Or, as i previously mentioned, 19 works.

Comment: Please explain why you would use these commands and what they would accomplish.

Comment: @JoshuaNurczyk the aspm=0 switch is to disable Active State Power Management (ASPM).  PCI-e supports ASPM, so I believe the post was meant to turn off any potential antenna power saving (and append this to the configuration file to make it persistent).  The rmmod and modprobe remove the kernel module and then reload it (to refresh the kernel driver after the aforementioned network interface configuration was changed).